# How should I handle and query Geospatial data efficiently in GridDB?

Tags: griddb

I have been using GridDB to handle time-series data in my project and it's been performing so well. However, the project scope has expanded to include geospatial data alongside the time-series data. Now, I'm looking into how GridDB handles geospatial data.

I have gone through the documentation, but I didn’t find much regarding the support for geospatial data types or queries.

My question is,
Does GridDB support geospatial data types and geospatial queries?
If it does, what are the data types and functions available for handling geospatial data?